# R: memory efficient way to replace column values by index

Tags: r, dataframe, memory

I have two very large dataframes, df1 and df2 with two columns "ID" and "Value".
The first dataframe is larger.
All values in the column "ID" from df2 also occur in df1, but not vice versa.

I want to replace all values of column "Value" in df1 with the values of df2, for the ID's which df1 and df2 share.

Although with smaller dataframes this is quite simple (see exaple below), I'm running into memory issues with my larger dataframes (*"Error: cannot allocate vector of size X"*).
**I wonder is there is a more memory-efficient way to do the following:**

```
mydf  <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 3, 4, 2, 5),
                    A  = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
#>   ID A
#> 1  1 1
#> 2  3 2
#> 3  4 3
#> 4  2 4
#> 5  5 5

mydf2 <- data.frame(ID = c(2, 3, 1), 
                    A  = c("a", "b", "d"),
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
#>   ID A
#> 1  2 a
#> 2  3 b
#> 3  1 d

# Result
keys  <- match(mydf2$ID, mydf$ID)
mydf$A[keys] <- mydf2$A
#>   ID A
#> 1  1 d
#> 2  3 b
#> 3  4 3
#> 4  2 a
#> 5  5 5
```

The error occurs at the last line, (mydf$A[keys] <- mydf2$A), which cannot be completed because of it.

Comment: When does `cannot allocate vector of size X` happen, at `keys <-` ?

Comment: how large is your data frame? where does the error occur? what is the output of `memory.limit()` or `gc()`

Comment: @chris Yes  
@mnist it occurs at "mydf$A[keys] <- mydf2$A"  
My memory.limit() is  7970, gc() gives 
           "used   (Mb) gc trigger   (Mb)  max used   (Mb)
Ncells  12789864  683.1   20111346 1074.1  17231944  920.3
Vcells 625412473 4771.6 1154478611 8808.0 961842984 7338.3". The object.size(mydf) gives 2279025904 bytes, object.size(mydf2) gives 2279044048 bytes
and object.size(mydf2$A) gives 26087672 bytes
```